# angular 2 typescript class library analog

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript

I'm new in web application and now I try to understand angular2 architecture. For example, I have a system of 2 web applications - internal web application for employees and e-shop for clients. In each of this applications I have the same component - table with products info. Is there any way to create this component in one project (as class library in C#) and create references to it and use in each of 2 web applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. You need to create a module (`NgModule`) which you will import to both applications.

You could package this module into an npm package for easy consumption (you'll need a private npm repository for this if you don't want to share your module).

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me any suggestion how to do it in visual studio 2015? What project type shall I use?

Comment: Is it's strictly a javascript project I would use a more lightweight editor like VS Code. Just create a folder with your `package.json`, `tsconfig.json`... and so on.